# Is there a way to suppress "x rows affected" in SQLCMD from the command line?

Tags: sql-server, rows, sqlcmd, suppress

Is there a way to suppress "x rows affected" in SQLCMD from the command line?

I'm running an MSBuild script and don't want it clogging up my log on my build server.

I'd rather not have to add "SET NOCOUNT ON" in every script, so if there's a way to do it from the command line, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

What about creating a startup script with SET NOCOUNT ON in the script (assign the script to the SQLCMDINI environment variable). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Yep - just simply adding SET NOCOUNT ON; to your export query (or query file) will help this.

Comment: But if the script has `GO` commands in it, the `NOCOUNT` setting will be reset after every `GO` will it?

Answer (score 60):

The `-i` and `-q` options [are mutually exclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Create a file named setnocount.sql with the content:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

And you might be able to do `-i setnocount.sql,otherscript.sql` using the multiple files feature and effectively an "included" common first file.

Answer (score 50):

You can also run multiple lines in the `-Q` parameter, separated by semicolon, like below

eg:

```
-Q "set nocount on;select * from table;delete from table where some_condition=true"
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore column name from the output?

Comment: you pass in `-h -1` meaning you don't want headers to be printed.