# Suppressing "X rows affected" in SQL Server using sqlcmd and Java

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlcmd

In my Java program, I am trying to execute a bunch of SQL scripts using `sqlcmd` via `getRuntime.exec()`.

Earlier, I had been using `osql` this way -

```
osql -n -S SERVER -U sa -P PASSWORD -q "SET NOCOUNT ON" -i "INPUTSCRIPT.sql"
```

However, in the case of `sqlcmd`, the `-i` and `-q` switches are mutually exclusive. How do I do this in `sqlcmd`?

**Note:**

1. I'd rather not modify the SQL scripts to include `SET NOCOUNT ON` in
   each file.
2. There's already been a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014129/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-x-rows-affected-in-sqlcmd-from-the-command-line). That solution discusses setting environment variables. Is that possible using Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify multiple scripts for the `i` switch so you can do this:

```
sqlcmd ... -i SetNoCountOn.sql,MyScript1.sql,MyScript2.sql
```

That is, create a an extra script that just has `SET NOCOUNT ON`

Comment: This works like a charm. But when I execute thousands of scripts, there is quite a noticeable (but not much) hit on the process time. Is there any way to improve on that?