# Save results to txt file without any other formatting in sqlcmd

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd, osql

When i run this command:
`sqlcmd -S server -U sa -P xxxxxxx -i d:clients.sql -o D:\clients.txt`
but in file i have x rows affected, "1> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> 8>" and many other spaces
I wan't only result without any formatting.
In sql file i have some selects.

Thank in advance.

Comment: "1> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> 8>" hide when use sqlcmd before i used osql

Answer (score 1):

You can add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your script to [remove the `rows affected` message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014129/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-x-rows-affected-in-sqlcmd-from-the-command-line) and add [`-h-1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to the command line to remove the column names and the lines underneath them. This works for me and returns row data only:

```
sqlcmd -E -i query.sql -o tmp.txt -h-1
```

Where `query.sql` looks like this:

```
set nocount on;
select name from sys.objects;
```

But I don't know where the `1> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6> 7> 8>` characters are coming from. You may want to post a minimal example of a SQL script that gives that output.

And as a general comment, I personally don't like to use sqlcmd.exe for running queries because it's difficult to control the output. Some other things to consider are:

- Use bcp.exe if you want a delimited file
- Use a script in PowerShell, Perl or whatever language you prefer
- Use an SSIS package
- Put your script contents into a stored procedure and execute it instead of using an input file