# How do I suppress the output of a sql query executed through a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am executing an sql script through a batch file

```
sqlcmd /S<machine> /Usa /Paaa123  /i "<sql file>" > "results.txt"
```

After the above gets executed the resultant file has  "(8890 rows affected) " as a part of the result file which I want to suppress.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014129/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-x-rows-affected-in-sqlcmd-from-the-command-line

Comment: More explanation and a example would help.

Comment: That is right David.Not sure if I can mark this question as redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to export the result of the query execution, just remove the `> "results.txt"` part.

`sqlcmd /S /Usa /Paaa123 /i ""` is what you should run

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd /S<machine> /Usa /Paaa123  /i "<sql file>" | findstr /v /c:"rows affected" > "results.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd /S<machine> /Usa /Paaa123  /i "<sql file>" | findstr /v /g:"file with unwanted spam" > "results.txt"
```