# How to set a sqlcmd output to a batch variable?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, for-loop, batch-processing, sqlcmd

I'm trying to set the output of a sqlcmd query to a variable in a batch file.

Here's my query:

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -Q "select max(Column1)+1 from Table1"
```

This gives me exactly what I would expect and what I want:

```
-----------
         10
<1 rows affected>
```

However, when I try to set it to a variable, I used this script:

```
for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -Q "select max(Column1)+1 from Table1"') 
    do set ColumnVar=%%a
echo %ColumnVar%
pause
```

This gives me this result instead: `<1 rows affected>` I'm guessing this is because the loop is setting the variable to the last line. So is there a way I could use tokens and delims to parse out the 10 instead?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but [this SO post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014129/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-x-rows-affected-in-sqlcmd-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that question when I was searching.

Comment: Hello, this won't work unless you put the do command on the same line as the for loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try turning on NOCOUNT:

```
for /f %%a in ('sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select max(Column1)+1 from Table1"') do set ColumnVar=%%a
echo %ColumnVar%
pause
```

Comment: That works perfect. Only one thing I had to modify was change `"delims="` to `"delims= "` to get just the numerical output. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: I am storing the sql command in a batch variable; Can you suggest me how can i do this with my variable?