# How to display number of rows affected in a text file sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I am using a batch file to run SQL statements from another file. How do I log the result or error message on a text file in same folder. Here is what I have done:"

```
@echo off
sqlcmd.exe -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -i C:\SQLBatch\CreateLinkServer.sql -o C:\SQLBatchCreateLinkServer.txt
```

The log file (SQLBatchCreateLinkServer.txt) only contains "Changed database context to 'master'.". How do I get the batch to write all the details in the log such as no. of rows affected and which query is being excuted.

Thank you

Comment: In your .sql do you have the command `set nocount on`? If so, remove it, or add a script for `set nocount off`. See the opposite approach done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2014129/1422451).

Comment: I will set it to off and give you feedback. Thank you

Comment: setting nocount to off didn't do the trick

Comment: @Parfait. Thank you. it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from Parfait helped resolve the issue.

I had this

`@echo off
sqlcmd.exe -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -i C:\SQLBatch\CreateLinkServer.sql -o C:\SQLBatchCreateLinkServer.txt`

instead of

`@echo off
sqlcmd.exe -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -i C:\SQLBatch\CreateLinkServer.sql -o C:\SQLBatch\CreateLinkServer.txt`

hence the count not writing to specified file.

The difference is that instead of the name of the file being SQLBatchCreateLinkServer.txt, it should have been CreateLinkServer.txt in a folder named SQLBatch

Comment: What is the difference between these two commands? It is not readily clear. Include it in the body of answer.